# YSlow not working for newest chrome version

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, mozilla, yslow

Well this performance tool has been removed automatically when i received an update over chrome for version 67.X
Trying to download this extension, but the error is shown as "Invalid Manifest".  Does anyone is getting the same error, if yes then any solution.

Moreover, i tried installing in Mozilla Firefox (Version 45.0).  Installed successfully, only problem is that it's not visible on the toolbar.

[![This is my firefox snippet][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0GXK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0GXK.png)

Answer (score 0):

This has been addressed in this [github forum](https://github.com/marcelduran/yslow/issues/197):

> Further inspection shows that Chrome 67.x requires "manifest_version":
>   2 to be present in manifest.json, as explained in
>   https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.
>
> You can unpack the CRX file using 7-Zip, modify manifest.json as
>   described above, and then go to Chrome's chrome://extensions/,
>   activate Developer Mode, and Load Unpacked.